# How to add url slug to existing data in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, url, slug

I have a site of books. My books table contains fields id,title,pdf  and body and I hav posted about 4000 books and my books show the url like https://www.bookspk.site/2017/12/barre-sagheer-pak-o-hind-me-ilam-e-hadith.html. but now I am created url field and able to use url slug with this code

```
function string_limit_words($string, $word_limit) {
$words = explode(' ', $string);
return implode(' ', array_slice($words, 0, $word_limit));
}
$blog='';

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
$title=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
$body=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['body']);
$title=htmlentities($title);
$body=htmlentities($body);
$date=date("Y/m/d");

$newtitle=string_limit_words($title, 6);
$urltitle=preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i',' ', $newtitle);

$newurltitle=str_replace(" ","-",$newtitle);
$url=$date.'/'.$newurltitle.'.html';
```

but the problem is that how can I insert url slug my already posted data thanks in anticipation for kindness and answer this stupid questionand

Comment: I don't see any code to save that info in the database

Comment: mysql_query("insert into blog(title,body,url) values('$title','$body','$url')");

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you asking if SQL has a statement to update existing rows?

Comment: yes of course I want to update my url field which is empty with the help of above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the question, but if you are trying to get slugs for all the previous records that were inserted in your database before you added the code that now creates your slug. You have to create a query that selects all the records that don't have a slug, call the function that creates your slug and update each record with the correct value.

(Edit)
First off, you should not use mysql_query anymore because it has been deprecated since 5.5.0. Here is example of the code you could use :

```
$res = $mysqli->query('SELECT id, title FROM table WHERE slug = ""');
while($obj = $res->fetch_object()){
   $newtitle=string_limit_words($obj->title, 6);
   $urltitle=preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i',' ', $newtitle);
   // AND HERE UPDATE YOUR TABLE WITH A WHERE ID = $obj->id
}
```

Comment: absolutely wanted this please provide me little more help in sql query to update url slug

Answer (score 1):

Here is an version of Johnny Dew's code , and since i cannot comment yet , I am posting this as a answer ..

```
    $res = $mysqli->query('SELECT id, title FROM table WHERE slug = ""');
    while($obj = $res->fetch_object()){
       $newtitle=string_limit_words($obj->title, 6);
       $urltitle=preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i',' ', $newtitle);

       // AND HERE UPDATE YOUR TABLE WITH A WHERE ID = $obj->id
        $mysqli->query('UPDATE table SET slug=$urltitle WHERE ID = $obj->id');
    }
```

You probably will want to use a slug class/function to generate better slugs from title , other than by just replacing alphanumeric characters with space